# Could not retrieve generated id after insert nhibernate sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, last-insert-id

I am building an C# application using NHibernate and SQL Server. When I try to save an entity (using identity generator) I get the error 'Could not retrieve generated id after insert'. Does anyone know why I actually get this error? Did I misconfigure something? How should I fix this?

I have done this a thousend times in MySQL without any problems.
Thank you.

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SubscriptionType] (
SubscriptionTypeID      INT             NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
Name                    VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY(SubscriptionTypeID)
);
```

Hibernate mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="Studshake"
                   namespace="Studshake.Models">

  <class name="CompanySubscriptionType" table="[SubscriptionType]" lazy="false">
    <id name="SubscriptionTypeID" column="SubscriptionTypeID">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="Name" column="Name" />

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Error:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): 'LAST_INSERT_ID' is not a recognized built-in function name.]

Comment: Because nhibernate hasn't been told that SQL Server uses SCOPE_IDENTITY() and not LAST_INSERT_ID?

Comment: Aah oke, probably stupid question but how do I set nhibernate to use SCOPE_IDENTITY() ?

Comment: Sorry, don't know. Are you sure nhibernate knows through config that you are using SQL Server?

Comment: You're great, thank you! I was still using NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect in stead of NHibernate.Dialect.MsSQL2012Dialect.

Answer (score 0):

The really significant advantage of NHibernate *(ORM in general)* is that we do not have to solve the specific SQL syntax of currently used DB engine. And if we manage to use the standardized API of NHibernate - we can ran our code almost against any DB Engine. The only important setting is **DIALECT**, which allows NHibernate to properly convert that into DB engine related SQL:

#### [3.5.1. SQL Dialects](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#configuration-optional-dialects)

> You should always set the dialect property to the correct NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect subclass for your database. This is not strictly essential unless you wish to use native or sequence primary key generation or pessimistic locking (with, eg. ISession.Lock() or IQuery.SetLockMode()). However, if you specify a dialect, NHibernate will use sensible defaults for some of the other properties listed above, saving you the effort of specifying them manually.

So, if the previous code was running with setting related to MySQL

```
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
```

Now, when working with SQL Server, we need its Dialect

```
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect</property>
```

Comment: Some might consider that a disadvantage. Proprietary extensions exist for a reason, and generic "solve this problem for all platforms" ORMs have to ignore those by definition.